# How to document mixed array return type?

Tags: php, phpdoc

What is the correct syntax to document an array of mixed strings and ints?

```
public function toArray(): array
{
    return [
        'string',
        42,
    ];
}
```

Here are the options I've considered:

```
/**
 * @return string|int[]
 */
```

But this seems to indicate it would either be a `string` or an `int[]`

```
/**
 * @return string[]|int[]
 */
```

And this would seem to indicate either an array of strings *or* an array of ints.

Comment: is your function return only `string` or `int` array or it can return `mixed` array with `string` and `int` value ?

Comment: if your function returned mixed array then go for last one otherwise go for corresponding one. You can write `@return string Array || int Array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
@return (int|string)[]
```

More details on [phpdoc](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/types.html)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on [this document](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/types.html#arrays)

at the last last bottom of the page

**specified containing multiple types, the Type definition informs the reader of the type of each array element. Each element can be of any of the given types.**

```
 @return (int|string)[]
```

Also have a look on [return](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html) in case needed more details.